# Add commons-math3 dependency to xtext maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, xtext

I have xtext language server project configured to build with maven. With the default dependencies, the project build is working fine with

```bash
mvn clean install -U -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

But now I need to add [commons-math3](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-math3) as a dependency. I have added the following to xtext's pom.xml

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

When I run the above maven command, I see that the jar files are downloaded in `~/.m2/repositories` folder

```bash
./org/apache/commons/commons-math3
./org/apache/commons/commons-math3/3.6.1/commons-math3-3.6.1.pom
./org/apache/commons/commons-math3/3.6.1/commons-math3-3.6.1.jar.sha1
./org/apache/commons/commons-math3/3.6.1/commons-math3-3.6.1.pom.sha1
./org/apache/commons/commons-math3/3.6.1/commons-math3-3.6.1.jar
```

But when I try to use it in my code, the imports are not resolved:

```java
import org.apache.commons.math3.geometry.euclidean.threed.Rotation;
import org.apache.commons.math3.geometry.euclidean.threed.RotationOrder;
import org.apache.commons.math3.geometry.euclidean.threed.Vector3D;
```

I need to "search repositories "org.apache.commons.math3.geometry.euclidean.threed'" and select the found artifact to the target platform (though I am not sure what does this actually do -- `git status` does not show changes in any of the files).
[image]

After this, I need to add the package to `MANIFEST.MF` file

```
Require-Bundle: org.apache.commons.math3;bundle-version="3.6.1"
...
Import-Package: org.apache.commons.math3;bundle-version="3.6.1"
```

After this I am able to run the IDE project from Eclipse with "run as Eclipse application", and everything works as expected. But at this stage if I run the maven command, I get the error:

```bash
[ERROR] Cannot resolve project dependencies:
[ERROR]   Software being installed: com.example.xtext 1.0.0.qualifier
[ERROR]   Missing requirement: org.example.xtext 1.0.0.qualifier requires 'osgi.bundle; org.apache.commons.math3 3.6.1' but it could not be found
```

Do I need to add `<repository>` in pom.xml? But the jar is downloaded, meaning it has been properly located. Or am I missing something in the `<build>` stage in pom.xml?

**Edit 1:** If I start with a clean maven project (without xtext), adding the dependency works without any additional steps. So some configuration in xtext is not allowing the dependency to be found.

**Edit 2:** In some old project I found that the external dependencies have be installed in `~/.m2/repository/p2/osgi/bundle/` folder. Is that the only way for a dependency to be found?

Comment: You should not use `<scope>import</scope>` you should remove that simply.

Comment: sorry I was just fooling around. Even after removing it I get the same error

Comment: Am I right assuming the nature of your project is an OSGI bundle? My experiences with OSGI are limited and I never found out how Maven and OSGI go well together. I remember that besides adding a dependency to the MANIFEST the JAR itself has to be added to a specific directory. Check whether you find that directory and try adding your JAR to this directory. If this works maybe you'll find a mechanism that this happens automatically.

Comment: if you want to use maven artifacts in eclipse code you need to do this one:
https://läubisoft.gmbh/en/articles/using-maven-artifacts-in-pde-rcp-and-tycho-builds/

Comment: but as commons math is already there: https://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/simrel/orbit-aggregation/2023-09/ you can use that one in your target directly

Comment: Thanks! "nature of your project is an OSGI bundle" where can I find that out? Are xtext projects by nature OSGi bundle?

Comment: added the following in my xtext.target file 
```
<location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="false" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
   <unit id="org.apache.commons.math3" version="3.6.1.v20221112-0806"/>
   <repository location="https://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/simrel/orbit-aggregation/release/4.29.0"/>
  </location>
```

Comment: finally works after adding the bundles to MANIFEST.mf as well and <repository> to pom.xml

Comment: if you use manifest then adding to target should be sufficient without adding anything in the pom. the nature of your project depends on what you select in the new xtext project wizard